# Shuffle an array of images

Tags: php, javascript

I have an array of images that I want to display in a random order, 1 image at a time. I think a solution would be to shuffle the array when someone visits the page and then use an onclick event to call each image. When all of the images have been called, the array would either loop or, ideally, re-shuffle. How can I do this?

Comment: check [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681786/php-random-links-without-repeating/10681963#10681963) answer of mine, which does somehow what you want using <a>nchors instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks helpful: http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_1/article_317-array-shuffle-function . Just put your image url's in an array then shuffle it. Display the first one, then every time its clicked move on to the next one. When you reach the last one, also reshuffle the array onclick and start over at the beginning.

Comment: How do I apply the function to the array and how do I call it on the page?

Comment: Paste in the `Array.prototype.shuffle = function()...` code from that page I linked to on your page, then use `Your_Array.shuffle()` to shuffle the array.

Comment: By putting the shuffle inside the body's onload attribute, you're causing the array to be shuffled after the page loads, and therefore after you display the images. Put it in the head tag right after your other code.

Comment: When a visitor reaches the end of the array, instead of returning again to the first image from their session, how could I have the array reshuffle?

Comment: Call `your_array.shuffle()` in addition to resetting the image number variable.

Comment: Use brackets on your if statement `{ }`.

Answer (score 1):

.See [`shuffle()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

```
<?php
    $images = array(
        0 => 'image1.gif',
        1 => 'image2.gif',
        2 => 'image3.gif',
        3 => 'image4.gif',
        4 => 'image5.gif',
    );
    shuffle($images);
    foreach ($images as $image){
        echo sprintf('<img src="%s">', $image);
    }


?>
```

Comment: Why did you use `sprintf` instead of just using concatenation? `echo '<img src="' . $image . '">';`

Comment: It makes it easier to read and write. Less opportunity for quoting issues.

Comment: Is this possible to do with javascript?